# Swagger error due to dependency in .NET 5 with Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, autofac, swashbuckle

I'm trying to add Swagger to my .NET 5 application so I've added configuration

Configure method:

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
   app.UseSwagger();

   app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
   {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint($"/swagger/{nameof(My_app).ToLower()}/swagger.json", "My_app");
   });
 }
```

And ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
 {
     options.SwaggerDoc(nameof(SRW_CRM).ToLower(), new OpenApiInfo { Title = "MyApp" });

     options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
     {
         Name = "Authorization",
         Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
         Scheme = "Bearer",
         BearerFormat = "JWT",
         In = ParameterLocation.Header,
         Description = "JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme."
     });

     options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
     {
         {
             new OpenApiSecurityScheme
             {
                 Reference = new OpenApiReference
                 {
                     Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                     Id = "Bearer"
                 }
             },
             Array.Empty<string>()
         }
     });
 });
```

But constantly when I'm opening application I have an error:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: 'An exception was thrown while activating Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.'

> DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider apiDescriptionsProvider' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorOptions, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.IApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider, Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ISchemaGenerator)'.

Does it mean that I have to register it somehow via autofac too?

Comment: Where's the rest of ConfigureServices? Did you [read the docs](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#swashbuckle-apiexplorer-and-routing)?

Comment: Thanks. Adding `services.AddControllers()` was sufficient :)